# 'React' must be in scope when using JSX react/react-in-jsx-scope

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mern, eslintrc

I am new in MERN Stack. I am following my prof's session videos in this project but suddenly I come across this error while she doesn't have any issues on her side.
I also tried to use the methods I found as I was searching but it still won't work.
This is my very first time in asking here, I don't know if any of you will reach me out soon but I'm just hoping.
Anyway, here's my snippet of codes.

[This is the product.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTHUZ.png)

[ProductScreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZoU0.png)

[App.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdpwm.png)

[HomeScreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjzys.png)

P.S. I already did two says that suggested here also in stackoverflow. The first one is to capitalize the React when you import it like this

import React from 'react';

The other one is to modify the rules in .eslintrc.json

```
    "react/jsx-uses-react": "off",
    "react/react-in-jsx-scope": "off"
```

Comment: I think you need to import React ProductScreen

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to add `import React from 'react'` on top of ALL your components (ProductScreen, App, Homescreen, and every other component) ?

Comment: I just tried it now, but it still won't work.

Comment: Okay...
Now it doesn't have any warnings or error in the terminal when I follow your instructions, but it still won't display anything.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you use version 6 of react-router-dom. using it is slightly different from v5. Check the doc here : https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview and modify app.js accordingly

Comment: Hello. It now works. I follow my classmate's advice to downgrade the react-router-dom to 5.2.0. It might be like what you said. 
Many, many, many thanks to you for helping me!!!